# Log4j, get env. variable in Appender

Tags: log4j, environment-variables

I am using XML log4j configuration, and in my xml i have next
This code doesn't work, no output file

```
   <appender name="FA" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="${MYVARIABLE}/output.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
```

this also doesn't work

```
<param name="File" value="${env.MYVARIABLE}/output.log"/>
```

If I set

```
<param name="File" value="D:/output.log"/>
```

logging works well

Any ideas, how get env. variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy env. variable to properties

```
String result = System.getenv("MYVARIABLE");
System.setProperty(property.toLowerCase(), result);
```

And now

```
<param name="File" value="${myvariable}/output.log"/>
```

works well